# adding to tail of linked list of pointers to structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, singly-linked-list

I'm basing this off of code that appends to a linked list of structs, and I've now moved to using pointers of structs for a new project, and I can't get the code to work, there is no output. When I run it through debug mode I find that my method of appending to the end of the linked list isn't working.

Here are my structs
I use a struct for holding the linked list because it's better than using a head pointer on its own.

```c
typedef struct competitor competitor;
typedef struct ll_competitor ll_competitor;

struct competitor {
    int data;
    competitor *next;
};

struct ll_competitor {
    struct competitor *head;
    int size;
};
```

This just makes a pointer to a struct, stores the passed data and returns it

```c
competitor* make_competitor(int data){
    competitor *competitor_ptr;
    competitor_ptr = malloc(sizeof(competitor));

    if (competitor_ptr != NULL){ // if malloc was successful
        competitor_ptr->data = data;
        competitor_ptr->next = NULL;
    }
    return competitor_ptr;
}
```

This *should* add an item to the end of the linked list

```c
void insert_tail_competitor(ll_competitor *ll, competitor *insertion){
    competitor *temp_pointer;
    temp_pointer = ll->head;

    while (temp_pointer != NULL){ // while not null aka until the end of this chain
        temp_pointer = (temp_pointer)->next;
    }
    temp_pointer = insertion;
}
```

This should iterate over the linked list, outputting the data

```c
void print_all_competitors(ll_competitor *ll){
    printf("Print all competitors");
    competitor *temp_ptr = ll->head;
    int counter = 0;
    while (temp_ptr != NULL){
        printf("\nCount: %d\n", counter++);
        printf("data: %d",temp_ptr->data);
        temp_ptr = temp_ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Builds the linked list for me

```c
ll_competitor *make_competitor_ll(){
    ll_competitor *ll = malloc(sizeof *ll); // do a linked list builder later
    ll->head=NULL; ll->size=0;
    return ll;
}
```

Main initialises 5 pointers to competitors using the make_competitor function, I expect an output of
1
2
3
4
5

```c
int main() {

    ll_competitor *ll = make_competitor_ll();

    competitor* c1 = make_competitor(1);
    competitor* c2 = make_competitor(2);
    competitor* c3 = make_competitor(3);
    competitor* c4 = make_competitor(4);
    competitor* c5 = make_competitor(5);


    insert_tail_competitor(ll,c1);
    insert_tail_competitor(ll,c2);
    insert_tail_competitor(ll,c3);
    insert_tail_competitor(ll,c4);
    insert_tail_competitor(ll,c5);

    print_all_competitors(ll);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: To clarify my confusion, here is the code I based this off of

```c
typedef struct node_tag *node_pointer;

typedef struct node_tag{
    int data;
    node_pointer next;
}node;

void insert_at_tail(node_pointer *pointer_to_head, node_pointer new_node_pointer){
    node_pointer *temp_pointer;
    temp_pointer = pointer_to_head; 
    while (*temp_pointer != NULL){
        temp_pointer = &(*temp_pointer)->next;
    }
    new_node_pointer->next = *temp_pointer;
    *temp_pointer = new_node_pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing `insert_tail_competitor` does is define a local variable named `temp_pointer` and then change that pointer several times, so we would not expect that function to have any lasting effect on the data in your program.

If you want to add an entry to your linked list, you actually need to modify the `next` pointer of a struct.

Maybe this would work:

```c
void insert_tail_competitor(ll_competitor * ll, competitor * insertion)
{
  competitor *  c = ll->head;
  if (c == NULL)
  {
    ll->head = insertion; 
    return;
  }

  while (c->next != NULL) { c = c->next; }
  c->next = insertion;
}
```

(By the way, for more maintainable code, you'd probably want to find some way to handle the special `c == NULL` case the same way as the other cases, but let's keep it simple for now.)

Comment: I will try this, would you be able to comment on my edit? I'm confused why that code works (albeit in a slightly different context) but the new code does not.

Comment: Also, i'm not sure what you mean by finding a way to handle the c==NULL case. Is this not the appropriate way to handle it? As it is something that will occur every time a fresh linked list is made

Comment: It's just kind of inelegant that we have to write `= insertion` twice and makes it a little harder to test the code.

Comment: In the code you added to your question `temp_pointer` is a *pointer to a pointer* so when you write to `*temp_pointer` you are actually modifying a pointer in your linked list instead of just modifying a local variable.